# iOS -- AVAssetReaderTrackOutput Memory Leak

Tags: ios

I'm getting so frustrated with this.

I'm examining an AVAsset frame by frame by hooking up an AVAssetReaderTrackOutput instance to an AVAssetReader.

If I use this code, everything works fine but there is a memory leak:

```
while ([reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) {
    CMSampleBufferRef buffer = [trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
    if(!buffer) break;
    if(/* some condition that alerts me I want to get the image for this frame  */) {

        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer);
        // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer.
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer.
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        // Get the pixel buffer width and height.
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

        // Create a device-dependent RGB color space.
        static CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = NULL;
        if (colorSpace == NULL) {
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        if (colorSpace == NULL) {
            // Handle the error appropriately.
            return nil;
            }
        }

        // Get the base address of the pixel buffer.
        void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
        // Get the data size for contiguous planes of the pixel buffer.
        size_t bufferSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(imageBuffer);

        // Create a Quartz direct-access data provider that uses data we supply.
        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider =
        CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, baseAddress, bufferSize, NULL);
        // Create a bitmap image from data supplied by the data provider.
        CGImageRef cgImage =
        CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, bytesPerRow,
                        colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little,
                        dataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

        // Create and return an image object to represent the Quartz image.
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
        CGImageRelease(cgImage);

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

        [/* array of UIImages */ addObject:image];
    }
    else CFRelease(buffer);
}
```

There is a memory leak because I am only releasing the CMSampleBuffer if I don't want a UIImage from it.

However, this code does not cause a memory leak, but it causes the array of UIImages to be empty when it's all over:

```
while ([reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) {
    CMSampleBufferRef buffer = [trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
    if(!buffer) break;
    if(/* some condition that alerts me I want to get the image for this frame  */) {

        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer);
        // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer.
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer.
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        // Get the pixel buffer width and height.
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

        // Create a device-dependent RGB color space.
        static CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = NULL;
        if (colorSpace == NULL) {
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        if (colorSpace == NULL) {
            // Handle the error appropriately.
            return nil;
            }
        }

        // Get the base address of the pixel buffer.
        void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
        // Get the data size for contiguous planes of the pixel buffer.
        size_t bufferSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(imageBuffer);

        // Create a Quartz direct-access data provider that uses data we supply.
        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider =
        CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, baseAddress, bufferSize, NULL);
        // Create a bitmap image from data supplied by the data provider.
        CGImageRef cgImage =
        CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, bytesPerRow,
                        colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little,
                        dataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

        // Create and return an image object to represent the Quartz image.
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
        CGImageRelease(cgImage);

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

        [/* array of UIImages */ addObject:image];
    }
    CFRelease(buffer)
}
```

Why on Earth does releasing the CMSampleBufferRef mess everything up when it causes a memory leak when I don't release it?

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Comment: By the way, I don't think that you should **conditionally** release the buffer - it always needs to be released if it's created.

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing this in Xcode. And I know I shouldn't conditionally release it; I'm trying to figure out why releasing it causes the image generation to fail.

Comment: No problem, it's a common source of misunderstanding - you could use `emacs` and `make` as well, the question would still be about the Cocoa Touch API :)